# Can I use the Ekcalendar in my native iphone apps

Tags: iphone, events, calendar, eventkit

I plan to create a meeting/event iphone application.  Can I use the Ekcalendar inside my apps(not the default calendar apps on the iphone)? When I click the meeting detail, it will have my own define fields to insert/update/delete? If not, what is the alternative class that has similar functions (show day, week, month views)

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can try Ekcalendar. I have used a very nice calendar. it is Kal calendar.Here is the link. Try using it.

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Hope this helps you. :]